# Wpf Combobox in Master/Detail MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, wpf-controls

I have MVVM master /details like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type model:EveryDay}">
    <views:EveryDayView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type model:EveryMonth}">
    <views:EveryMonthView/>
</DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="12,24,0,35" Name="schedules"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentElement}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120"/>
    <ContentControl Margin="168,86,32,35" Name="contentControl1"
        Content="{Binding Path=CurrentElement.Schedule}" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="188,24,51,0" Name="comboBox1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
           ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=Schedules}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentElement.Schedule}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
           SelectedValuePath="ID"
           SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentElement.Schedule.ID}"/>
</Grid>
```

This Window has DataContext class:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MainViewModel() {
        elements.Add(new Element("first", new EveryDay("First EveryDay object")));
        elements.Add(new Element("second", new  EveryMonth("Every Month object")));
        elements.Add(new Element("third", new EveryDay("Second EveryDay object")));

        schedules.Add(new EveryDay());
        schedules.Add(new EveryMonth());
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ScheduleBase> _schedules = new
        ObservableCollection<ScheduleBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<ScheduleBase> Schedules {
        get {
            return _schedules;
        }

        set {
            schedules = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Schedules");
        }
    }

    private Element _currentElement = null;
    public Element CurrentElement {
        get {
            return this._currentElement;
        }

        set {
            this._currentElement = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentElement");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Element> _elements = new
        ObservableCollection<Element>();
    public ObservableCollection<Element> Elements {
        get {
            return _elements;
        }

        set {
            elements = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Elements");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

One of Views:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.EveryDayView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid >
    <GroupBox Header="Every Day Data" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBox  Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Path=AnyDayData}" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

My SelectedItem in ComboBox doesn't works correctly. Are there any visible errors in my code?

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  What behavior are you seeing with SelectedItem?  Is it never getting updated?  Inconsistently?

Comment: I need edit element property Schedule that selected in ListBox by ComboBox and after that by UserControls. ListBox and ComboBox are bound by CurrentElement in ModelView. To select item - selectedItem of ComboBox use function Equals() of Types EveryDay and EveryMonth. This function compares pointers of Element.Schedule in ListBox and Schedule in ComboBox and them of course not equals. Behavior that I expect from ComboBox that objects of one class taken to be equivalent. I can send you code. Thank you Ben Von Handorf .

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is bind the items of an `ItemsControl` to an `ICollectionView` (usually ListCollectionView) instead of directly to a collection; I think that's what the `ItemsControl` does by default anyway (creates a default `ICollectionView`), but I might be wrong.

Anyway, this allows you to work with the `CurrentItem` property of the `ICollectionView`, which is automatically synchronized with the selected item in an `ItemsControl` (if the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property of the control is true or null/default). Then, when you need the current item in the ViewModel, you can use that instead. You can also set the selected item by using the `MoveCurrentTo...` methods on the ICollectionView.

But as I re-read the question I realize you may have another problem altogether; you have a collection of 'default' items and need a way to match them to specific instances. It would however be a bad idea to override the equality operators of the objects to consider them always equal if they are of the same type, since that has the potential to make other code very confusing. I would consider extracting the type information into an enum, and put a read-only property on each object returning one of the enum values. Then you can bind the items to a collection of the enum values, and the selected item to the enum property of each object.

Let me know if you need an example, I may have made a mess of the explanation :)